# Enable key login without password

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I would like to use chef to enable key login without password between vm1 and vm2.
I know the manually steps are:

1. ssh-keygen -f id_rsa_2 -t rsa -N ''  on vm1
2. copy the content of generated id_rsa.pub, login to the vm2 with username and password, add the content the authorized_keys on vm2

Then I can login to vm2 from vm1 without any password.

Now when using chef, I would like to dynamically generate the key pair.
Then with a shell script on vm1(need to pass the password of vm2 to this shell script) to put public key on vm2.
So I need to put the password of vm2 somewhere(may in one attribute), but I do not want to store the password directly or with simple encryption.

Is there any more secure way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would go the other way around,
Save the generated public key on node data of vm1 and then on vm2  go ask for vm1 attribute (using search to get the "partner" host) and write the public key in the `allowed_hosts` file (with a template).

This way you don't have to connect from vm1 to vm2 and send a password, the drawback is that search can lag for a while, so it will probably take 2 run on each machine before the desired state is obtained.

Another option could be to use chef-vault to store vm2 password and allowing only vm1 to read it.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this with Chef would be to make the relevant keys ahead of time and store them somewhere (chef-vault for example, though that isn't a great option), and then use Chef only to configure the relevant files as needed. Using Chef data for this kind of autonomous cluster management is possible but very tricky to do right, easier to just specify things in a top-down manner.